# Single interface to values from Array or Hash

Tags: ruby

Trying to get the values out of a collection that could be either an `Array` or a `Hash`, but switching based on type seems awkward:

```
def values_from_collection(array_or_hash)
  case array_or_hash
  when array_or_hash.is_a? Array
      array_or_hash
  when array_or_hash.is_a? Hash
      array_or_hash.values
  end
end
```

Is seems like there should be a single interface/method that both classes support, but nothing obvious stands out in `Enumerable`.  Is there a standard way to accomplish this?

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem so to me. Hash and Array are very different data structures. Why do you think they should support this?

Comment: `if array_or_hash.respond_to? :values/array_or_hash.values/else/array_or_hash/end`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you appear to be right, I thought other languages supported a standard iterator that could accomplish this but I appear to have mis-remembered.  Please feel free to add this comment as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @elliot42 There is a uniform iterator: `each`. The gotcha is that a hash, being that it consists of *pairs* of values, must yield both the key and value to the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it doesn't seem so to me. Hash and Array are very different data structures. Why do you think they should support this?

Anyway, you could, for example, monkey-patch Array class to add `values` method

```
class Array
  def values
    self
  end
end
```

And then your method is greatly simplified:

```
def values_from_collection(array_or_hash)
  array_or_hash.values
end
```

But this is worse than branching, in my opinion.

Comment: In that case, `values` should be used **instead** of `values_from_collection`.

Comment: @sawa: Yes, the method can be inlined now. But we don't see calling code, so I decided to leave it this way.